# How to exclude last three places of a string through regular expression ?

Tags: regex

How to exclude last three places of a string through regular expression ?

Sample string is:  "EFF PIONEER AGG BD N CAP PE"
output required is: "EFF PIONEER AGG BD N CAP"

Comment: You haven't said what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match  all the characters except the last three,

```
^.*(?=...$)
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/oX4qT1/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^` starting point.
- `.*(?=...$)` Matches upto the last three charcters. Lookahead is used for this purpose.
- `.` represents any character.
- `$` End of a line.

Comment: Thanks buddy! I will use this regex and will check and if it works fine with automated scheduled job. Have a good day!